# Validate Xml schema with xsd

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate the following Xml.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                    <ROOT xmlns:bk=""urn:samples"">
                        <RandomName1>
                            <Element1>v</Element1>
                            <Element2>v</Element2>
                            <Element3>v</Element3>
                            <Element4>v</Element4>
                    </RandomName1>
                        <RandomName2>
                            <Element1>v</Element1>
                            <Element2>v</Element2>
                            <Element3>v</Element3>
                            <Element4>v</Element4>
                    </RandomName2>
                    </ROOT>";
```

`RandomNameN` is any string. I am interested in ensuring that `Element1 - Element4` are present and named correctly and that the schema matches.

I have tried the following

```
string xsdMarkup =
                @"<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
                   <xsd:element name='ROOT'>
                    <xsd:complexType>
                     <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:any>
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name ='Element1'/>
                                <xsd:element name ='Element2'/>
                                <xsd:element name ='Element3'/>
                                <xsd:element name ='Element4'/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:any>
                     </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                   </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:schema>";

XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

bool errors = false;
string msg = string.Empty;

xDoc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) =>
    {
        msg = e.Message;
        errors = true;
    });
```

I am getting `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException`

> The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType' element is not
>   supported in this context.

I need to also know how to make the `RandomName1` nodes not require a name but be present. I've tried to acheieve this via `</xsd:any>` instead of `</xsd:element>`

Comment: You cannot define a complexType inside <xsd:any>. <xsd:any> refers to the type of the elements in the sequence not just their name. It allows the sequence surrounding it to contain any type of elements. You can however limit the possibilities by specifying the namespace. See: **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043.aspx**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143819/validate-xml-schema-with-xsd#comment26575933_18143819), the usage of `<xsd:any>` is incorrect.

Furthermore, `<xsd:sequence>` also cannot contain a complexType. See: **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256089.aspx**

I would also suggest not using patterns like RandomNameN to identify your elements but more like: `<RandomName id='N'>`. Speaking OO, you could think of your XSD as your Class definitions, with the `complexTypes` being the classes, and `elements` being references to instances of the `complexTypes` classes, therefore for elements you should also define their `type`.

Your XML document will then represent your Objects. Where the type of the Object is represented in the Tag.

Your complexType could be wrapped inside of an element. And since you have a variable number of elements in the sequence, you should set `maxOccurs` to unbounded. Your resulting Schema should look like this:

```
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
       <xsd:element name='ROOT'>
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="RandomName" maxOccurs='unbounded'>
                  <xsd:complexType>
                     <xsd:sequence>
                       <xsd:element name="Element" minOccurs='4' maxOccurs='4' type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
               </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
       </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>>
```

In which case your XML could look like this:

```
<ROOT >
     <RandomName>
        <Element>v</Element>
        <Element>v</Element>
        <Element>v</Element>
        <Element>v</Element>
     </RandomName>
     <RandomName>
        <Element>v</Element>
        <Element>v</Element>
        <Element>v</Element>
        <Element>v</Element>
     </RandomName>
 </ROOT>
```

Finally, if RandomName1 - RandonNameN are from the same type (or Class if we're speaking OO) then the tags in the XML file should also be the same. Same goes for Element1-Element4.

However, if they are of different types but have common elements, you could use inheritance.

`Element1` could look like this for example:

```
<complexType name="Element1">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="Element">
            <sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="additionalField"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the xml producer is under your control. If it is you could solve it e.g. using element with fixed name with some attribute containing random name, smth like `<FixedNameElement randomName="...">`.